# How to create a set for Id ? - In Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, set

I have a List and I am querying for 3 values Timecard Id, End date and Company ID. I want to create a set of company id.  I am trying to do the following but I am getting error.  Here company id is a lookup field and the values are something like this  **"XYZ solutions"**. So I have taken `Set<String>` instead of `Set<ID>`.

```
trigger Timecard on pse__Timecard_Header__c (after insert) {


  List<pse__Timecard_Header__c> tc_list = [select Id, pse__End_Date__c, pse__Project__r.pse__Region__r.ffpsai__OwnerCompany__r.Id 
                                             from pse__Timecard_Header__c
                                             where Id IN :Trigger.newMap.KeySet()];
    Set<String> tc_setofId = new Set<String>();
     for (pse__Timecard_Header__c tcId: tc_list)
        {
            String s = tcId.pse__Project__r.pse__Region__r.ffpsai__OwnerCompany__r.Id();
            tc_setofId.add(s);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: This is the error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [SOBJECT:c2g__codaCompany__c].Id()

Comment: @sus - That error does not match what you have in your code above, there is not place in that code that I see that has c2g__codaCompany__c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
String s = tcId.pse__Project__r.pse__Region__r.ffpsai__OwnerCompany__r.Id();
```

Is no valid syntax as a field is not a method. Methods use the () notation.

To get the ID of the OwnerCompany (Lookup field as you suggested) all you need is:

```
String s = tcId.pse__Project__r.pse__Region__r.ffpsai__OwnerCompany__c;
```

Comment: FYI: [Id](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_id.htm) is a data type so you could declare your Set as: `Set<Id>`. 

You may also need some null guards for `pse__Project__r` and `pse__Project__r.pse__Region__r`

Comment: @BarCotter - Valid points. Was only answering the direct question posed. There are all sorts of other things that could be said....

Comment: if you can help me here too..this is follow up question to this post http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57898/how-to-compare-values-in-for-loop-in-trigger